# Maatwebsite Excel for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, maatwebsite-excel

I have done the same thing before, however faced with an error on this code:

```
Excel::create('churros_contact', function($excel){
        $excel->sheet('contact', function($sheet){
            $sheet->fromModel(Contact::all());
        });
})->export('xlsx');
```

It says :

> ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory

Where can I modify the directory setting?
As for permission, I already set it, so it should be other issues..
What config might I have missed out?

If I change to XLS, it doesn't give me error, but it also doesn't download.

Comment: maybe you are missing some php extensions if that is a new machine? but if you use homestead then it shouldn't matter

Comment: well, this is in my localhost, and in previous project, i used the same thing, but nothing went wrong

Comment: @lewis4u : I have yet to find the solution. As i wondering where the error is, do you have any clue? Thank you before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public function csvOrderstatus($id)  
{
    $result = DB::table('order')->where('id',$id)->first();  // the data you want to download as csv

    $csv = (array)$result;  // stored the data in a array

    return Excel::create('csvfile', function ($excel) use ($csv) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function ($sheet) use ($csv) {
            $sheet->fromArray($csv);
        });
    })->download('xls');
}
```

This works for me. Hope this will help you.

Comment: what about many rows? ->where('id',$id)->take(10)->get()  doesnt work